# Optimization using indexes on joins in SQL

Tags: sql, join, indexing

This may seem quite basic but I have spent the last hour searching and can not find a direct answer.

Let's have two tables: `tblCustomer` and `tblStore`.

`tblCustomer` has a primary unique index of `CustomerNumber` and `Version`.

**Question 1**: if `tblStore` does not have `CustomerNumber` as its primary key, will I still get better optimization with a:

```
From 
    tblStore s 
Left Join 
    tblCustomer c On s.CustomerNumber = c.CustomerNumber
```

or is it better to have the  'on' be something that is an index for both tables?

**Question 2**: I only want rows where the customer version is 1. Should I say:

```
From 
    tblStore s 
Left Join 
    tblCustomer c On s.CustomerNumber = c.CustomerNumber 
                  And c.Version = 1
```

I imagine that is better for performance than doing it later in the `Where` clause, but does it make joining by index better or would `CustomerNumber` be enough on its own.

I am working on a query for something with quite a lot of rows, so any advice is helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're worried about join performance, use a simple incrementing integer primary key. Putting the condition into the `join` or `where` clause shouldn't matter for performance, but it can give different results.

Comment: From what I read, if I put a condition in the Where clause, it will initially pull back all of the rows and then limit them down when it gets to the Where clause. Is this not true?

Comment: That is not true at all. Predicate pushdown means that SQL Server can filter them even directly at the storage engine, when it loads the rows of disk.

Answer (score 2):

1. The optimizer may consider whether to rearrange as a right join, and whether to do a merge, hash or loop join, of which the first is usually best for a large number of sorted rows, the second for a large number of unsorted rows, the third usually best for a small number of rows.
   This query I assume would be selecting all stores and left joining all customers.  Generally you would want a merge join, so ideally you would index both tables on `CustomerNumber`. This does not have to be the primary key, it can be a secondary (non-clustered) index; nor does the primary key have to be the clustering index (the actual order of the table), it may also be a secondary index.
2. The difference between the two syntaxes is not performance, which the optimizer can work around, but correctness. If you place the filter in the `WHERE` you will filter out all `Stores` that have no `Customers`. The filter in the `ON` clause is usually the correct one. In an inner join it makes no difference whatsoever (even to performance).
   To optimize for this query, it would be better to place `Version` as the first column in an index, followed by `CustomerNumber`. Another option is a filtered index, but that is beyond the scope here.

I suggest you read up on indexing. [Brent Ozar](https://brentozar.com) may be a good place to start, also [Use the Index, Luke](https://use-the-index-luke.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I do have a book that I am working through to become more aware. I do not have access to update the indexes of the table. I am just creating reports using the data. 
So with that in mind, If i have table A joining table b, should I try and find a index they share? If one does not exist, is it better to join on A's index or B's index?

Comment: Join on whatever field is the correct one. Don't make something up to fit an index